# Very low quality flag active for long time

Tags: support, flags, low-quality-posts

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element/20319764#20319764).

I flagged it as 'very low quality' about a week ago. It appears that it was reviewed in the queue back in December 2013 (hence [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507138/how-do-i-add-a-class-to-a-given-element/20319764#comment30333942_20319764)), which, IIRC, was upvoted from `1` to `3` soon after my flag.

Why is it still active when the 'very low quality' queue is nearly always `0` questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because once a post has already been through the LQP queue, further NAA or VLQ flags will not send it back into that queue. Only moderators will be able to handle it past that point.

Problem? Well, we've gotten used to all those flags going into the LQP queue, so we don't pay as much attention to those two flag types in our queue anymore, as in we don't explicitly click on the "very low quality" or "not an answer" reasons to filter them. They just stay mixed in with the massive list of all flags, which is usually quite large because of all the custom flags.

Comment: large = roughly 1.2k+ today

Comment: Oh, I thought all of those *would* be handled by the queue, no matter the status, so I totally filtered them out. Didn't realize some wouldn't be.

Comment: Maybe you should then be able to filter out those the queue can handle still... (Though as the queue is always empty, that's moot, probably...)

Comment: @Deduplicator It would be nice to have some sort of indication that the flag will never get handled by the queue. As the system is designed, the flag has to exist for at least 15 minutes before it hits the queue. But there are also exceptions for posts which *never* qualify to go to the queue, like if it's an accepted answer. But the default, collapsed view of the post does not show us if it's accepted or not.

Comment: @animuson: Actually I meant more like splitting the VLQ-Flag in two: Those only mods can handle, and the rest you need not concern yourself with because the queue empties so fast, so you can mask them out.

Comment: Or just hide the ones that will go to the queue, kind of like close flags. No need for extra queues.

Comment: What about obviously off-topic questions. Flagged couple question in last couple days and all of them looks still active and as I said none of them disputed.

Comment: @mohacs Recommend closure flags **only** go to the Close Votes queue, moderators cannot see them in the flags queue at all.

Comment: @animuson if I did not understand wrong what you are saying, my flags are not visible to mods that is why not not evaluated until now?

Comment: @mohacs Right. They are only handled by the community through that review queue.

Comment: Oh I see thank you I got it now, if community doesn't care about it, even question is %100 off-topic remains there so the flag. Since I am not eligible vote for close, flagging kinda useless for me.